# Python: unable to convert list to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I able to get raw javascript raw data from a link to a list datatype but unable to convert it to Pandas Dataframe.

```
import re
import request

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get('http://www.sgx.com/JsonRead/JsonstData?qryId=RAll',headers=headers)

data = re.findall(r'items:(.*)',page.content)

print data
["[{ID:0,N:'2ndChance W200123',SIP:'',NC:'CDWW',R:'',I:'',M:'',LT:0,C:0,VL:0.000,BV:6099.000,B:'0.007',S:'0.009',SV:7278.300,O:0,H:0,L:0,V:0.000,SC:'5',PV:0.009,P:0,BL:'100',P_:'X',V_:''},{ID:1,N:'3Cnergy',SIP:'',NC:'502',R:'',I:'',M:'t',LT:0,C:0,VL:0.000,BV:130.000,B:'0.022',S:'0.025',SV:100.000,O:0,H:0,L:0,V:0.000,SC:'2',PV:0.021,P:0,BL:'100',P_:'X',V_:''},{ID:2,N:'3Cnergy W200528',SIP:'',NC:'1E0W',R:'',I:'',M:'t',LT:0,C:0,VL:0.000,BV:0,B:'',S:'0.004',SV:50.000,O:0,H:0,L:0,V:0.000,SC:'5',PV:0.002,P:0,BL:'100',P_:'X',V_:''}..}]}"
```

check the `type(data)`, it is shown as list.

However, when I `pd.DataFrame(data)`, the output does not shown as a proper dataframe. Instead, it is 
`0  [{ID:0,N:'2ndChance W200123',SIP:'',NC:'CDWW',...` a weird format.

How shall I get a neat and tidy dataframe?

Comment: If this API is returning JSON, it's doing a terribly poor job. I don't think this is data you can reasonably work with, it isn't even valid and therefore isn't parsable.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, it is working fine if with Javascript. In python, I need to use regex to modified the data. I am not sure if I do it correctly but I get it into a list.

Comment: This should Json format but invalid

Comment: can you print data?i think the problem is in data after re.findall,

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan , the print data is shown just below the `print data `command

Comment: print(len(data))

Comment: `print len(data)` return `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the **data** variable contains one string that should be a JSON string but not. I check the string, you could use the code below to make it a valid JSON string. Note it may fail if you get another **data** string.

```
data = data[0][:-1]  # remove the last element: "}" 

p = re.compile('(\w*?):(.*?)([,|}])')  # a key-value pattern, note that the last key-value ends with "}" rather than ","

def repl(m):
    # m is a regular Match Object. m.group(1) is the key; m.group(2) is the value; m.group(3) is the separator, maybe a "," if the key-value pair is in the middle of the string or a "}" if the key-value pair is in the end of the string.
    # return is a valid mini key-value pair, just add double quotes of the key, remain all other characters.  
    return '"' + m.group(1) + '":' + m.group(2) +m.group(3)

# find all the key-value pair of the data, and use the repl function to add double quotes.
# the original string contains single quotes, replace it to double quotes or you will get  "\'" in the string.
data = p.sub(repl, data.replace("'", '"'))  

data = json.loads(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

EDIT:

1、The last element of your string is "}", so firstly we remove it.

2、A valid JSON looks like **{"key": value}**, the key is in the double quotes. Your string looks like **{key: value}** without double quotes. We should find all the mini key-value pair, and add the double quotes for every key of them while remain the key and the value. The **repl function** aims to do this, using a pattern to find all the key-value pair of the data and then replace it with a new string with double quotes of the key.

Hope I explain clearly.

Comment: Thanks. It works finally. Could you add the elaboration for `def repl(m):`. Really a great answer if details elaboration of each step added.

Comment: @lotteryman, check my edit. I add some annotation and explain the key of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are calling the DataFrame constructer on a list of size 1.

Pandas is interpreting `pd.DataFrame(data)` as 'make a dataframe from this one element which is a string'.

You need to parse out the string into a json or directly retrieve the json via requests and then use the dataframe constructor.

Probably a better/ more robust way to do it but you can just play with the string to coerce the right format as below

```
import ast

# take item of data which is a string and remove xtra list layer in string
x = data[0].replace("[","").replace("]","")

# remove end parts and split into list of strings of the dicts
x = x[1:-3].split("},{")

# create list with correctly formatted string of dicts
items = [("{" + y + "}").replace('{','{"').replace(',',',"').replace(':','":') for y in x]

# Evaluate strings into dicts
dicts = [ast.literal_eval(item) for item in items]

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dicts)
```

Comment: I'm getting a SyntaxError when I set `data` as the response from that url, am I missing something?: https://bpaste.net/show/6e00e3820a18

Comment: Your data is a string, you can tell from the len of data, so you would not need to use `data[0]` just `data`. Mine returns data as a list len 1 from the below line.

I also had to use the slight variant `data = re.findall(r'items:(.*)',str(page.content))`

Comment: I already tested that and it's a SyntaxError again, that's why I was asking you. https://bpaste.net/show/7e38c43d0fd8  How are you testing this code?

Comment: Thats a confusing one, it works for me in an iPython Notebook...
https://snag.gy/BD9lZO.jpg

Comment: `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` is returned when input this command `dicts = [ast.literal_eval(item) for item in items]`

Comment: Pfft, it works for me with the exact code above. Confusing. My `len(data[0]) = 199672`

Comment: len(data) keeps changing but try printing these to find out where the requests module is giving us different results
https://snag.gy/GQRZNH.jpg.
Also check your requests version, mine is `requests==2.18.4`

Comment: @hilton92 Since strings are immutable in Python, each use of `str.replace` creates a whole new string, right? Maybe I'm just too tired but it seems like you are creating a minimum of `2 + (1049 * 3) == 3149` strings?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in how re.findall is returing data
it seems that data is a list containing one string.check len(data) ,it should return one.
You need to reprocess it .
Another thing is that your dictionary keys are not string,they are being treated as variable that are not defined. you need to make them as strings as show below

```
new_list=[{'ID':0,'N':'2ndChance W200123','SIP':'','NC':'CDWW','R':'','I':'','M':'','LT':0,'C':0,'VL':0.000,'BV':6099.000,'B':'0.007','S':'0.009','SV':7278.300,'O':0,'H':0,'L':0,'V':0.000,'SC':'5','PV':0.009,'P':0,'BL':'100','P_':'X','V_':''}]
>>> d=pd.DataFrame(new_list)
>>> d
           B   BL      BV  C  H I  ID  L  LT M ...     PV P_  R      S  SC SIP  \
    0  0.007  100  6099.0  0  0     0  0   0   ...  0.009  X     0.009   5       

           SV    V   VL V_  
    0  7278.3  0.0  0.0     

    [1 rows x 24 columns]
>>>
```

Comment: Make them strings... how? The easiest way I can think of is using JavaScript, `JSON.stringify` but I'm curious how you are doing this in Python? https://repl.it/repls/ImmaculateGainsboroEmulators

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the ugliest answer but it seems to work. The response from that url is a JavaScript object so my thought was to use `JSON.stringify` to parse it into proper JSON as shown here:

- https://repl.it/repls/ImmaculateGainsboroEmulators

One way to execute JavaScript's `JSON.stringify` from Python is to use Selenium's `execute_script` as shown below:

```
In[2]: import json
  ...: 
  ...: import pandas as pd
  ...: from selenium import webdriver
  ...: 
  ...: # Setup headless chrome
  ...: chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  ...: chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
  ...: driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
  ...: 
  ...: # Get response and return it as JSON
  ...: driver.get('http://www.sgx.com/JsonRead/JsonstData?qryId=RAll')
  ...: response = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/pre')
  ...: json_string = driver.execute_script(
  ...:     'return JSON.stringify({})'.format(response.text))
  ...: driver.quit()
  ...: 
  ...: # Convert to Python dict
  ...: json_data = json.loads(json_string)['items']
  ...: 
  ...: # Convert to DataFrame
  ...: df = pd.DataFrame(json_data)
In[3]: df.shape
Out[3]: (1049, 24)
In[4]: df.head()
Out[4]: 
       B   BL      BV      C      H I  ID      L     LT  M ...     PV P_  R  \
0  0.007  100  6099.0  0.000  0.000     0  0.000  0.000    ...  0.009  X      
1  0.022  100     0.1  0.001  0.022     1  0.022  0.022  t ...  0.021  X      
2         100     0.0  0.000  0.000     2  0.000  0.000  t ...  0.002  X      
3  1.110  100    51.0  0.000  1.110     3  1.110  1.110  t ...  1.110  X      
4  0.065  100     0.1  0.000  0.000     4  0.000  0.000    ...  0.080  X      

       S  SC SIP      SV        V    VL V_  
0  0.009   5      7278.3      0.0   0.0     
1  0.029   2        99.0   1097.8  49.9     
2  0.004   5        50.0      0.0   0.0     
3  1.120   A         6.9  68820.0  62.0     
4  0.083   2         0.1      0.0   0.0     

[5 rows x 24 columns]
```